# What is the Vahana of Goddess Durga as per Devi Bhagavatham?

Tags: goddess, durga, devi-bhagavata-purana, vahana

What is the scripturally correct vAhana of Durga Ma? I have seen Her pictures astride on both the lion and tiger. Please clarify from **Devi Bhagavatham.**  I am equally interested in knowing why tiger is also shown as a vahana of Goddess Durga if lion is what is the vahana per Devi Bhagavatham. So, kindly point out if she has two vahanas and if the vyaghra has ever been considered Her vehicle.

Comment: Devi mahatmya or Durga SaptasatI says lion as the vehicle of Devi. Devi Bhagavatam also says the same. @9bilvapatra

Comment: @Sarvabhouma The OP is asking for clarification from Devi Bhagavatam. The link that you gave has an answer from the Devi Mahatmya of the Skanda Purana.  Both are different sources.

Comment: @LazyLubber  Look at the question please. The same question is asked. It covers all the sources.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma I think this question (and answer) is specific to the Devi Bhagavatam. If you disagree, fine.

Comment: @LazyLubber As I said already, the other question covers all the sources. We can answer with all the sources including Devi. Bhagavatam. There are 18 Puranas. If there is a question "What is the vahana of Shiva" and after that "What is the Vahana of Lord Shiva according to Linga Purana/ Shiva Purana/ Skanda Purana/ other Puranas" this doesn't make 18 different questions but all are covered under the first question. Same here. We have to answer original questions but not answer duplicates and gain rep by that.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Who knows if the vAhana of Shiva or god xyz is mentioned differently in different sources? I don't know. The way I see it is - generally people answer questions which are new. There is no expectation that people are supposed to check for duplicates before answering a question.

Comment: @LazyLubber That is somewhere else. People are supposed to check for duplicates before asking on Stack Exchange and users are supposed to close as duplicate if it's one. Please familiarize yourselves with closing questions as duplicate and also [asking questions]( https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). "Please look around to see if your question has been asked before.". Then we can discuss further in chat.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma I understand that but new users may not know it. However, once a question is asked, people are free to answer. And "We have to answer original questions but not answer duplicates and gain rep by that." - This statement is almost trying to attribute motives to people who answer questions.

Comment: @Laz If you think so, so be it. The guidance in the faq says duplicate answering is discouraged. It's not a personal opinion. Leave about new users, it's the old users and years of stay disagree that questions should be closed as duplicate and ready to answer every question they see.  Am I influencing them? It's not new users. If someone wants to disobey it deliberately, I can't stop it. If someone wants to listen and follow the guidelines which are helpful for the site's progress, they are free to do. I use "should, have" because I feel the policies are written for the welfare of the site.

Comment: I don't know why Rules are being preached with respect to some members,  being forgotten in respect of some members.   This is called partiality.  In respect of many of my questions,  when I  was in receipt of down votes with out giving reasons,  no action was taken on those members.  Even I flagged the issue in Meta but the same was down voted again.  If the so called senior members want to run the site at their whims and fancies,  so be it.  What can members like me can do? This is not for you but for the moderators please @Lazy Lubber

Comment: @srimannarayanakv As your reputation increases you gain moderation abilities. As members gain more abilities there will be some inconsistencies as compared to previous times. Regardless, everyone should be discussing this on Meta (not here) and any attempts to change procedure should happen there as well

Comment: My intention of  continuing as a member in this site is to learn something,  which I don't know and to post answers in respect of questions,  which I know something.  I am raising certain issues just to make this site a transparent learning room for all,  which it is not allowed to be so. I neither  have ambition to become a moderator nor to gain reputation. @Rubellite Yaksi

Comment: @srimannarayanakv I was using "you" informally, meaning "anyone." The point wasn't your ambition, but that inconsistencies will exist by design because people get new abilities and use them a bit differently to each other (because we are not robots)

Answer (score 1):

***From Devi Bhavagatam***

Sudarśana, along with his newly wedded wife Śaśikalā, was proceeding to his preceptor's hermitage, when his enemies attack him.  Sudarśana began to recite silently the excellent one word seed mantra of the King of Desires (Kāmarāja) and, out of its power, he and his wife remained in the chariot without any fear and sorrow.

Thus when the dreadful war began to grow more and more horrible, the [Goddess Bhagavatī suddenly appeared there](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57156.html), ***mounted on Her lion***.

So Lion is Devi's vehicle.

Comment: Why is she sometimes depicted as seated on a tiger? Don't get me wrong, I love tigers :) .

Comment: @LazyLubber: May be tigers lovers depicted so :-)

Comment: You are probably right. Durga worship is very popular in Bengal and tigers are also loved in Bengal (Bengal tiger!).

Comment: @srimannarayanakv- All the Vaishno Devi pics have Goddess riding the tiger and Jai Mata Di written..so, is that a wrong depiction i mean iconographically..? I really don't know..tigers are sometimes symbols of animal instincts and Goddess controls it..

Comment: @srimannarayanakv- All the Vaishno Devi pics have Goddess riding the tiger and Jai Mata Di written..so, is that a wrong depiction i mean iconographically..? I really don't know..tigers are sometimes symbols of animal instincts and Goddess controls it..

Comment: I had a gone through the questions asked earlier and didn't find the answer.  If anybody has seen the answer kindly guide this new user.  Tks

Comment: @9bilvapatra: It is waste of time in asking for guidance here. The moderators of this site will respond to certain queries and to certain section of people only.